# Highcharts Line graph Error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I don't really know how to describe what is happening here, so if it is a duplicate I apologise.

This particular issue happens randomly.
I am using a line graph to draw multiple lines on a graph and sometimes they appear to 'fill'

The annoying thing here is it is random.  It doesn't always happen with this data set, it can happen with any lot of data and at any time.

Sometimes this happens when I hover over the lines, sometimes it is just there.
On the times that it is just there, it hides when I hover over it.

I am really at a loss as to what this is doing, anyone have any ideas?

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxeSF.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlHZ9.png)

Comment: Can you show a configuration/data set that exhibits the problem?  Or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, here is a stripped down version of the code that is used for the graph
https://jsfiddle.net/refineddigital/Ld3rzdwk/

Comment: I've refreshed this example a number of times and haven't seen the issue.  Are you able to reproduce it with this data set?  What browser are you using?

Comment: @barbaraLaird that is the issue, it doesn't always show, even with the same data set.  this data set is the same as one of the errors shown in the examples :(